# How to add multiple extra spaces b/w two variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have more than one space b/w two variables in javascript.
like

```
var firstname;
var lastname;
var result;

result = firstname +''+ lastname;
```

Here if i am +''+ b/w the variables , then its getting separated by only 1 space. How can i get more than one space?

if i tried with this :

```
result = firstname +'      '+ lastname;
```

but this also didnt worked out, still separating by only 1 space.

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` in html

Answer (score 1):

To add whitespace use `&nbsp;`

```
result = firstname +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+ lastname;
```